# entering Time date in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a Barcode reader to enter a serial number in 1 cell then automatically adding a date and time in the next two cells by using the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 5 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column <> 5 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target(1, 2).Value = Date
Target(1, 3).Value = Time
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I want be able to scan the barcode and either automatically find the serial number and place a date time stamp in two "other cells 4 & 5" or if that serial number is not in a cell place it there and put the date time in the 2 & 3 cells.

Comment: Where would the serial number be, other than in a cell?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you print the serial number to the sheet or do you just look it up? If you do print the  serialnumber to the sheet outside of `Worksheet_Change`, why don't you add the date and time stamp at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I asume your barcode reader is "tee-ed" into your keyboard cable and - so to say - sends key strokes to your PC. So as long as your Excel cursor is placed in the 5th column of your worksheet (2nd exit condition), the VBA code will add a date and a time into cells 1 & 2 right of your cursor (i.e. columns F..G) after each shot.

If you want to position date and time into the 2nd and 3rd collumn of your worksheet (i.e. columns B..C) irrespectively of where your cursor is at the time where the  Worksheet_Change trigger fires, you should use this code instead

```
Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = Date
Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, 3).Value = Time
```

Now ... looking up the captured barcode in another Excel table and find a matching serial number can be as simple as a VLOOKUP function you can automatically paste into the cell next to the date, or you can use a Do ... While ... Loop construct to scan a (named) range:

```
....
Target(1, 4) = SernoByBarcode(Target)
....
```

with

```
Private Function SernoByBarcode(Barcode As String) As String
Dim DBase As Range, Idx As Long

    Set DBase = Range("Database") ' named range "Database" contains Barcode in column1, SerNo in column2
    Idx = 2 'first row contains headers
    SernoByBarcode = "#NOT/FOUND" ' default return value

    Do While DBase(Idx, 1) <> "" ' break on 1st empty record
        If DBase(Idx, 1) = Barcode Then
            SernoByBarcode = DBase(Idx, 2)
            Exit Function
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

If you call Function SernoByBarcode before setting date & time you can use one more IF statement to determine the output format (i.e. includung/excluding Serial Number)

**Edit**

have barcode always scanned in same cell (I chose B2)
scan list starting in column 5 for existence of barcode ... if yes write into 8/9/10 else 5/6/7 ... Find function can be used with only little modification, now giving back row index rather than a string value

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Barcode always scanned into cell B2
' if barcode found in column 5, fill column 8,9,10 else fill columns 5,6,7
' row 1, columns 5..10 contain column headers
Dim Idx As Long

    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 2 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Idx = FindBarcode(Target.Value)

        If Me.Cells(Idx, 5) = "" Then
            Me.Cells(Idx, 5) = Target.Value
            Me.Cells(Idx, 6) = Date
            Me.Cells(Idx, 7) = Time
        Else
            Me.Cells(Idx, 8) = Target.Value
            Me.Cells(Idx, 9) = Date
            Me.Cells(Idx, 10) = Time
        End If

        ' keep cursor in Scan field
        Me.Cells(2, 2).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Function FindBarcode(Barcode As String) As Long
Dim DBase As Range, Idx As Long

    Set DBase = ActiveSheet.[E1] ' start of table
    Idx = 2 'first row contains headers

    Do While DBase(Idx, 1) <> "" ' break on 1st empty record
        If DBase(Idx, 1) = Barcode Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
    FindBarcode = Idx
End Function
```

Comment: barcode reader is a usb// curser is in cell column 5 row 2, scan the S/N. S/N is palced in Column 5 row 2 date is placed in column 6 row 2 and time is placed in column 7 row 2.  "If" I scan the same S/N in the file and columns 5-7 of row 2 are filled i want to place the same S/N in column 8 row 2 with date Column 9 row 2 and time in column 10 row 2..   Using this to check gas readers out to clients and then check them in at end of day

Comment: OK ... now it makes sense ... see EDIT